# Window background in plasma won't change

Tags: plasma-5

I went to System settings->Colors clicked on the Colors tab and changed my Window background to a gold then clicked on apply, that changed my scheme to Current and in the preview it shows the Window backgroud being gold but it is not gold when I open a new window. I have tried it with the Breeze,Breeze Dark and Honeycomb Color schemes but the window background always stays the same shade of grey. [This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj8Al.png)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be dependent on the GTK2 theme chosen.

I'm not sure if planned this way or is a bug, but it appears some colours are hard to set using Breeze as the GTK2 theme.

If you go to:

```
Settings -> Application Style -> GNOME Application Style (GTK)
```

and change the theme at 'select a GTK2 theme' your colors may work better on a different theme.